# Make a php calculator class using oops concepts

Tags: php, oop

Hi guys i am trying to make a php calculator class which need to multiple numbers through fucntion like when user try to run like this through commpand line claculator.php add 2,3,4,5,6 and it should give output as 20 and it should allow add method to use a new line character \n as a number separator  example calculator.php add `2\n 3,4`

And it should allow defining what delimiter is used to separate numbers example:
calculator.php add `\\;\\2;3;4`

And it should not accept negative numbers too.And if user pass  number as  more than 1000 it shouwld ignoe and give me the result exmaple php calculator.php add 10,20,1010,20 and it should ginore 1010 and give out put as 50

And i have tried this code which will accept only 2 parameters

```
 class Calculator {
    private $_val1 , $_val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2){
        $this->_val1 = $val1;
        $this->_val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function add(){
        return $this->_val1 + $this->_val2;
    }

    public function subtract(){
        return $this->_val1 - $this->_val2;
    }

    public function multiply (){
        return $this->_val1 * $this->_val2;
    }

    public function divide () {
        return $this->_val1 / $this->_val2;
    }
}

$calc = new Calculator(3,4);
echo "<p>3 + 4 = ".$calc->add(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (15,12);
echo "<p>15 - 12 = ".$calc->subtract(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (20,2);
echo "<p> 20 * 2 = ".$calc->multiply(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (20,2);
echo "<p> 20 / 2 = ".$calc ->divide(). "</p>";
```

Can anyone help me out how can i do those things

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the input expressions be nested, with parentheses, e.g. `1 + (2 * 5)` ?  If so, then you'll need to write some sort of parser.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen No actually input has to go with comma separated numbers can you please help me out how can we resolve that by using oop concepts trying to solve it from past few days but not getting result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

## Calculator class

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculator class
 */
class Calculator
{
    const min = 0;
    const max = 1000;

    /**
     * Calculate the summation
     * @param Array $number
     * @return integer
     */
    public static function add( $numbers ){
        return array_sum( self::_filter_numbers( $numbers ) );
    }

    /**
     * Substract numbers
     * @param Array $numbers
     * @return integer
     */
    public static function subtract( $numbers ){
        $filtered_numbers = self::_filter_numbers( $numbers );
        $first_number = array_shift( $filtered_numbers );
        return ( $first_number - array_sum( $filtered_numbers ) );
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the product of the given numbers
     * @param Array $numbers
     * @return integer
     */
    public static function multiply( $numbers ){
        return array_product( self::_filter_numbers( $numbers ) );
    }


    /**
     * Divide the given numbers
     * @param Array $numbers
     * @return double
     */
    public static function divide( $numbers ){
        $filtered_numbers = self::_filter_numbers( $numbers );
        $first_number = array_shift( $filtered_numbers );
        return ($first_number / array_product( $filtered_numbers ));
    }


    /**
     * Filter Invalid numbers
     * @param Array $numbers
     * @return Array Valid Numbers
     */
    private static function _filter_numbers( $numbers ){
        return array_filter( $numbers, function( $number ){
            return self::_is_valid_number( $number );
        } );
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given number is in the interval [0, 1000]
     * @param integer $number
     * @return boolean
     */
    private static function _is_valid_number( $number ){
        return ( $number >= self::min && $number <= self::max );
    }
}
```

## Tests

```
$test_numbers_1 = [ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1000, 2000 ];
printf( "<h4>Test 1</h4>\n" );
printf( "<p>Numbers: %s</p>\n", implode( ',', $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Add: %d</p>\n", Calculator::add( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Substract: %d</p>\n", Calculator::subtract( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Multiply: %d</p>\n", Calculator::multiply( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Divide: %f</p>\n", Calculator::divide( $test_numbers_1 ) );

$test_numbers_1 = [ -2, -1, 1, 2, 1000, 2000 ];
printf( "<h4>Test 2</h4>\n" );
printf( "<p>Numbers: %s</p>\n", implode( ',', $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Add: %d</p>\n", Calculator::add( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Substract: %d</p>\n", Calculator::subtract( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Multiply: %d</p>\n", Calculator::multiply( $test_numbers_1 ) );
printf( "<p>Divide: %f</p>\n", Calculator::divide( $test_numbers_1 ) );
```

## Test results

```
<h4>Test 1</h4>
<p>Numbers: -2,-1,0,1,2,1000,2000</p>
<p>Add: 1003</p>
<p>Substract: -1003</p>
<p>Multiply: 0</p>
<p>Divide: 0.000000</p>
<h4>Test 2</h4>
<p>Numbers: -2,-1,1,2,1000,2000</p>
<p>Add: 1003</p>
<p>Substract: -1001</p>
<p>Multiply: 2000</p>
<p>Divide: 0.000500</p>
```

Comment: if i gave -2,-3 liek this it should show error saying that negavtive numbers -2,-3 wont allow

Comment: > And it should not accept negative numbers too.And if user pass number as more than 1000 it shouwld ignoe and give me the result exmaple php calculator.php add 10,20,1010,20 and it should ginore 1010 and give out put as 50

Comment: Yes it is not accepting but it should give me error message with what negative numbers we have given i forgot to add there

Comment: And willl it accept if i gave numbers like this 2\n 3,4 ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$opt = getopt('s:n:m:');

try{
    if(!array_key_exists('n', $opt)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Missing parameter "n"');
    }

    if(!array_key_exists('m', $opt)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Missing parameter "m"');
    }

    if(array_key_exists('s', $opt)){
        $calc = new Calculator($opt['n'], $opt['m'], $opt['s']);
    }else{
        $calc = new Calculator($opt['n'], $opt['m']);
    }

    echo $calc;
}catch(Exception $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

/**
 * Class Calculator
 */
class Calculator{

    /**
     * Min allowed value
     */
    const MIN = 0;
    /**
     * Max allowed value
     */
    const MAX = 1000;

    /**
     * Operators
     */
    const OPERATORS = ['add'      => '+',
                       'subtract' => '-',
                       'multiply' => '*',
                       'divide'   => '/'];

    /**
     * Separator
     * @var string
     */
    private $separator = ' ';
    /** @var array */
    private $numbers = [];
    /** @var string */
    private $method;

    /**
     * Calculator constructor.
     *
     * @param string $numbers
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $separator
     */
    public function __construct(string $numbers, string $method, string $separator = ' '){
        $this->separator = $separator;
        $this->method    = $method;
        $this->numbers   = $this->parseNumbers($numbers);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(){
        return $this->{$this->method}();
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function add(): float{
        return (float)array_sum($this->numbers);
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function subtract(): float{
        $numbers = $this->numbers;
        $result  = array_shift($numbers);
        foreach($numbers as $number){
            $result -= $number;
        }

        return (float)$result;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function multiply(): float{
        return (float)array_product($this->numbers);
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function divide(): float{
        $numbers = $this->numbers;
        $result  = array_shift($numbers);
        foreach($numbers as $number){
            if($number == 0){
                throw new Exception('Div by zero.');
            }
            $result = $result / $number;
        }

        return (float)$result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $numbers
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function parseNumbers(string $numbers): array{
        $numbers = explode($this->separator, $numbers);
        $numbers = $this->checkNumbers($numbers);
        $numbers = array_map(function($value){
            $value = trim($value);
            if(is_numeric($value)){
                return (float)$value;
            }
        },
            $numbers);
        $numbers = array_filter($numbers,
            function($value){
                return ($value !== null);
            });

        return (array)$numbers;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $numbers
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function checkNumbers(array $numbers): array{
        return array_filter($numbers,
            function($value){
                if($value < 0){
                    throw new Exception('Negative numbers not allowed');
                }

                return ($value >= self::MIN AND $value <= self::MAX);
            });
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string{
        try{
            $numbers = $this->numbers;
            $output  = array_shift($numbers);
            foreach($numbers as $number){
                $output .= ' '.self::OPERATORS[$this->method].' '.$number;
            }
            $output .= ' = '.$this->calculate();

            return trim($output);
        }catch(Exception $exception){
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
php index.php -m add -n "1 2 3 4 5" // print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
php index.php -m subtract -n "1 2 3 4 5" // print 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 = -13
php index.php -m multiply -n "1 2 3 4 5" // print 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
php index.php -m divide -n "1 2 3 4 5" // print 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 = 0.0083333333333333

php index.php -m add -s ";" -n "1;2;3;4;5" // print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
php index.php -m add -n "1 2 3 4 5 2000" // print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
php index.php -m divide -n "0 1 2 3 4 5" // print 0 / 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 = 0
php index.php -m add -n "1 2 3 4 5 -20" // print Negative numbers not allowed
php index.php -m divide -n "1 0 2 3 4 5" // print Div by zero.

php index.php -m add -n "1
2 3 4 5" // print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

Comment: Will it accept if i added numbers like this  1\n 2,3,4,5